# Is "Absolutely Anything" a remake?

Tags: absolutely-anything

Today I saw a trailer for the forthcoming Simon Pegg / Monty Python film [*Absolutely Anything*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1727770/).  The plot, as far as I can tell from a trailer, is identical to that of the 1936 H.G.Wells classic [*The Man Who Could Work Miracles*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0029201/)

I haven't found any interview or article that mentions that H.G.Wells was taken as inspiration but the similarities are striking.

Is *Absolutely Anything* a remake of / inspired by *The Man Who Could Work Miracles*?  Is it just coincidence?

Comment: To me it looks more like *Bruce Almighty*. Or *Bedazzled*. Or *Click*. Or many other comedies where someone is gifted with near omnipotence...

Comment: @Walt, there is no omnipotence in either version of Bedazzled.  Bruce Almighty carries a different moral.  I haven't seen Click.  Although I take your point, there are similarities with other films.

Comment: Maybe not per se in *Bedazzled*, but the power to wish for *anything* is in the same ballpark, really, and leads to similar humorous results when it backfires. And seriously, this new one even has the potty-trained-dog jokes from *Bruce* and Beckinsale from *Click*. :/

Comment: @Chenmunka Click is about a magic remote control that gives the user control over all aspects of their life (seemingly), like the passage of time, their colour scheme, muting...

Comment: I am 100% sure it is a remake. Zero coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an interview The director sites

> "I thought I'd do the H. G. Wells story The Man Who Could Work Miracles, but it just changed out of all recognition from that." - Jones

http://www.empireonline.com/interviews/interview.asp?IID=1858